# How can I read binary image file using Core Graphics?

Tags: image, matlab, core-graphics

I created an image in Matlab and changed it into binary image file.
I want to read in the file using Core Graphics APIs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [ImageIO](http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/workingwithimageio.html) framework with raw data.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't say what format your *binary image file* is in I will recommend [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). It is a powerful image processing library which has bindings for many languages.

You can use it to transform your  *binary image file* into a format that Core Graphics can understand.